# How to get config head setting to set page og:title in Nuxt2 (vue.js)?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, seo, facebook-opengraph

I am using Nuxt.js to build my project.

I have set the `head` in `nuxt.config.js` and want to get the settings in the page.

```
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
    ...
    head: {
        title: 'SITE NAME',
        titleTemplate: '%s | SITE NAME',
        meta: [
            { charset: 'utf-8' },
            { 'http-equiv': 'X-UA-Compatible', content: 'IE=edge' },

            { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
            { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'SITE DESCRIPTION' },

            { hid: 'itemprop-name', itemprop: 'name', content: 'SITE NAME' },
            { hid: 'itemprop-description', itemprop: 'description', content: 'SITE DESCRIPTION' },
            { hid: 'itemprop-image', itemprop: 'image', content: process.env.BASE_URL + '/assets/img/og_img.png' },

            { hid: 'og:site_name', property: 'og:site_name', content: 'SITE NAME' },
            { hid: 'og:title', property: 'og:title', content: 'SITE NAME' },
            { hid: 'og:description', property: 'og:description', content: 'SITE DESCRIPTION' },
            { hid: 'og:url', property: 'og:url', content: process.env.BASE_URL },
            { hid: 'og:image', property: 'og:image', content: process.env.BASE_URL + '/assets/img/og_img.png' },
            { hid: 'og:image:width', property: 'og:image:width', content: '1200' },
            { hid: 'og:image:height', property: 'og:image:height', content: '630' },
            { hid: 'og:type', property: 'og:type', content: 'website' },

            { hid: 'twitter:card', name: 'twitter:card', content: 'summary_large_image' },
            { hid: 'twitter:title', name: 'twitter:title', content: 'SITE NAME' },
            { hid: 'twitter:description', name: 'twitter:description', content: 'SITE DESCRIPTION' },
            { hid: 'twitter:image', name: 'twitter:image', content: process.env.BASE_URL + '/assets/img/og_img.png' }
        ],
    },
}
```

```
// about.vue (page.vue)
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            pageTitle: 'PAGE TITLE',
            description: 'PAGE DESCRIPTION',
        }
    },
    head () {
        return {
            title: this.pageTitle,
            meta: [
                { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: this.description },

                { hid: 'itemprop-name', itemprop: 'name', content: `${this.pageTitle} | SITE NAME` },
                { hid: 'itemprop-description', itemprop: 'description', content: this.description },

                { hid: 'og:title', property: 'og:title', content: `${this.pageTitle} | SITE NAME` },
                { hid: 'og:description', property: 'og:description', content: this.description },

                { hid: 'twitter:title', name: 'twitter:title', content: `${this.pageTitle} | SITE NAME` },
                { hid: 'twitter:description', name: 'twitter:description', content: this.description }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I try to use `this.title`, `this.$config`, `this.$route.meta`, all of them are wrong.

[image]

How can I get the `nuxt.config.js` settings in the page?

Nuxt version: 2.14.5

Node version: 14.16.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no declarative way to get all `Nuxt` configs that exist in the `nuxt.config.js` file.

`head` property in the `nuxt.config.js` is for adding general `head` elements to all your pages.

If you want to store a global configuration throughout the project for example the `SITE NAME`, you need to use `publicRuntimeConfig`

```
   publicRuntimeConfig: {
    siteName: 'SITE NAME'
  }
```

Then you can use it in any component by `this.$config.siteName`

For more resources.

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/nuxt-config/#publicruntimeconfig

Comment: Thank you! This has helped me a lot with my questions.